# Ionic 3 DOC File not open in android

Tags: ionic3, doc

I am trying much example code from here but it is not working, PDF file successfully opened, but doc/Docx file not open.

I am getting this error:

> Error opening file: {"status":9,"message":"Activity not found: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://io.ionic.starter.opener.provider/external-cache/Complex Numbers.docx typ=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document flg=0x40000003 }"}

Help me, if anyone get success.

Comment: Your are passing a wrong MimeType . that's why the openFile Plugin  is not working properly

Comment: What can I do for it, I mean open doc file. Actually I have a doc URL link, from this link, I want to view doc file on the ionic app screen.